# Joomla Migrating Live Site To Localhost -Navigation Not Working

Tags: php, sql, joomla3.8

I just migrated a Joomla site from live to localhost. Have the front end up and can access the backend without problem.

Front end wise none of the menu items work.

I have renamed the live site variable to point to `http://localhost/domain`. I also disabled SSL via config and disabled .htaccess files.

Permissions have been added for tmp and cache directories where required. Wondering what else I could be missing. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Wondering if this could be db or file related, relevant details below

```
public $live_site = 'http://localhost/Clients/domain';
public $log_path = 'F:\\ClientDevEnvs\\htdocs\\Clients\\domain\\logs';
public $tmp_path = 'F:\\ClientDevEnvs\\htdocs\\Clients\\domain\\tmp';
Have also edited httpd.conf file to enable and enabled htaccess mod_rewrite.
```

Comment: Did you checked cache,tmp folders are there at frontend ?

Comment: Hi John, sure did. Initially I had to create the tmp and cache folders as these were missing but this was one of the first things I was doing as I couldn't login without them.

Comment: Please add the htacces file to your question and what happen if you click on a menu item (redirect / error).

Answer (score 1):

It's usually best to leave the `$live_site` parameter empty. In addition to removing/renaming your `.htaccess` file (which you already did), make sure your `configuration.php` file has the following settings:

```
public $live_site = '';
public $sef_rewrite = '0';
```

The second line will disable URL rewriting. You can also change this setting under "Configuration" from the Joomla back end.

On a side note, if you use [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/download/akeeba-backup) and [Kickstart](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-kickstart.html) to backup and restore your site, the tool usually takes care of updating all required settings.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your advice on this. Sadly I had tried this before earlier yesterday and not had any joy. I have actually come across this issue in the past and used this method to resolve. Ideally keeping sef urls active would be better but at the moment I just want to get the front end working lol

Comment: Check the RewriteBase entry in the htaccess file.